# FormulArray in VBA doesn't give the correct result

Tags: vba

I am an office bearer of a Residential owners assoc. I keep track of expenses and receipts in an excel form and generate summary containing list of defaulters and rct details of those who have paid. I created a payment ledger with cols A to J. The summary status list is in col M to V. I use array formula to calculate "rct no." or "not paid" status scanning thru the Ledger table.

Since the array calculation is very slow I wanted to replace the individual calculation with a macro. I created a simple sample macro to use a simple formulaArray as the complete formula returns error.

This macro is called "test". However when I run it does not give correct value for the variable "final" which is value at N5. The code may not be efficient but it is just to try out and make it work in the first place. Any help to make the last line work is welcome. Refer link for the sample excel file.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rct As String
    Dim dday As String
    Dim ddate As String
    Dim dmonth As String
    Dim dyear As String
    Dim final As Variant

    Range("z3").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($A$1:$I$200,MATCH(1, (Month_Adjusted=N$2)*(Flat_No=$M5),0),6)"
    Range("aa3").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($A$1:$I$200,MATCH(1, (Month_Adjusted=N$2)*(Flat_No=$M5),0),1)"
    rct = Range("z3").Value
    Range("ab3").Formula = "=day(aa3)"
    dday = Range("ab3").Value
    Range("ac3").Formula = "=MONTH(aa3)"
    dmonth = Range("ac3").Value
    Range("ad3").Formula = "=YEAR(aa3)"
    dyear = Range("ad3").Value
    final = Application.concatenate(rct & "" / "" & dday & "" - "" & dmonth & "" - "" & dyear)
    Range("n5").Value = final
End Sub
```

actual Formula used at cell N5 in non VBA sheet is

```
=IF(ISERROR(CONCATENATE((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$M5),0),6)),"    /    ",DAY((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),1))),"-",MONTH((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),1))),"-",YEAR((INDEX($A$1:$K$j58,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),1))))),"Not Paid",CONCATENATE((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),6)),"    /    ",DAY((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),1))),"-",MONTH((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),1))),"-",YEAR((INDEX($A$1:$j$958,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m5),0),1)))))
```

[check non sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QuapLS_lyYXXY3sr50Tkkvajl_l-6PcKJJ4qWh00xw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your line saying

```
final = Application.concatenate(rct & "" / "" & dday & "" - "" & dmonth & "" - "" & dyear)
```

has two double-quotation marks where I suspect you only want one, i.e.

```
final = Application.concatenate(rct & "  /  " & dday & "-" & dmonth & "-" & dyear)
```

---

But there is no point in using `Concatenate` to concatenate what is only a single string value, you may as well just use:

```
final = rct & "  /  " & dday & "-" & dmonth & "-" & dyear
```

And, because your `dday`, `dmonth` and `dyear` values are all just determined by a single date, that could be replaced with:

```
final = rct & "  /  " & Format(Range("AA3").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

(Strictly speaking, you are currently generating the date using a `"d-m-yyyy"` format, but IMO `"dd-mm-yyyy"` will usually look better in your output.)

Comment: Thanks for yr help. I think the problem was with single vs double quotes. when using inside "Formula" or "Formularrarray" double quote is needed.. I just modified the code without changing quotes                                   the line .final = Application.concatenate(rct & "" / "" & dday & "" - "" & dmonth & "" - "" & dyear) still returns type mismatch error though I dont see mismatch errors . is this line correct (just for academic interest.

Comment: @rameshjey But please don't use `Application.Concatenate` when you can do that (and **are** doing that) in native VBA using the concatenate (`&`) operator.

Comment: @YowE3K nice, is it mornng / night ? doesn't really matter, does it ;)

Comment: @rameshjey The statement `rct & "" / "" & dday & "" - "" & dmonth & "" - "" & dyear` will give a type mismatch error because (if I am right in the order it will parse the line) you are trying to divide an empty string by an empty string (i.e. the bit saying `"" / ""`).  Similarly, you are trying to subtract an empty string from an empty string (`"" - ""`).  (FWIW - By adding brackets so that the statement was maybe `(rct & "") / ("" & dday & "") - ("" & dmonth & "") - ("" & dyear)` it would have succeeded in doing a calculation, but that is certainly not what you wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for your help. Now  I have been able to make the code work with suitable error handling. Some of the errors were I presume due to the fact that there were no records for a given month or a given apartment leading to” N/A”values that translated to type mismatch error. Now I have handled that.

The issue is I want the fixed values N$2, $M3 and Range(“n3”) replaced by a suitable  iterative process so that I can step thru the matrix M10:v10 calculating the values at each cell one by one.  I tried using variable inside like (Month_Adjusted=N$i) and (Flat_No=$Mj) and  Range("ni").Value = final but it gives problems inside “formulaarray” calculation. The Error thrown is  “Unable to set the formulaArray property of the range class” Any help is appreciated

```
Sub test_working()
```

‘ final working code for calculating one cell at N3

```
Dim rct As String
Dim dday As String
Dim ddate As String
Dim dmonth As String
Dim dyear As String
Dim final As Variant

Worksheets("Ledger").Select
Range("z3").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($A$1:$I$200,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=N$2)*(Flat_No=$M3),0),6)"
Range("aa3").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($A$1:$I$200,MATCH(1,(Month_Adjusted=n$2)*(Flat_No=$m3),0),1)"
Range("z4").Formula = "=if(iserror(z3),""Not Paid"",z3)"
Range("aa4").Formula = "=if(iserror(aa3),""**"",aa3)"
rct = Range("z4").Value
final = rct & "  /  " & Format(Range("AA4").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Range("n3").Value = final
end Sub
```